# SignalR structuremap dependency resolver ( specified for Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.IMessageBus )

Tags: signalr, structuremap

how can i resolve this error ?

versions

Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.2.0, structuremap 3.1.4.143

global.asax signalR dependency resolve

```
// SIGNALR DEPENDENCY RESOLVER
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver(Container ?? ObjectFactory.Container);
```

StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver

```
public class StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;
    public StructureMapSignalRDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        object service = null;
        //Below is a key difference between this StructureMap example, GetInstance is used for concrete classes.
        if (!serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface && serviceType.IsClass)
        {
            //If the type is a concrete type we get here...
            service = _container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }
        else
        {
            // Non concrete resolution which uses the base dependency resolver if needed.
            service = _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
        }
        return service;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        var objects = _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType).Cast<object>();
        return objects.Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
    }
}
```

erorr

No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.IMessageBus'

There is no configuration specified for Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.IMessageBus

1.) new AckSubscriber(*Default of IMessageBus*, *Default of IAckHandler*)
2.) Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.AckSubscriber
3.) Instance of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.AckSubscriber
4.) Container.GetInstance(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.AckSubscriber)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try to resolve from the base class first.

```
    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null)
            return null;

        var service = base.GetService(serviceType);
        if (service != null) return service;

        return (!serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface && serviceType.IsClass)
            ? container.GetInstance(serviceType)
            : container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
    }
```

Comment: I am quite sure that from SM version 3 there is no difference between `container.TryGetInstance(serviceType)` on interface or concrete type so I would use just `return container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);`

Comment: @LetMeCodeThis I was thinking the same, but curiously it didn't work when I tried to simplify it like that.

Answer (score 1):

@ajm answer above bypassed the error for me, however I found that none of my client-side methods were being invoked.

It turned out that `SignalR.Infrastructure.PrincipalUserIdProvider` was being resolved instead of my custom `IUserIdProvider` so I had to modify his answer slightly by adding a container check first.

```
    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null)
            return null;

        var service = _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
        if (service != null) return service;

        return (!serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface && serviceType.IsClass)
            ? _container.GetInstance(serviceType)
            : _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
    }
```

The secondary container checks are still necessary if you are **not** using StructureMap 3 as `TryGetInstance()` returns `null` for concrete types.

Answer (score 0):

I found temporary, but error continues..
how can i registry this {Name = "AckSubscriber" FullName = "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.AckSubscriber"}

temporary solution is try catch, in catch return null

```
    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {

        try
        {
            object service = null;
            //Below is a key difference between this StructureMap example, GetInstance is used for concrete classes.
            if (!serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface && serviceType.IsClass)
            {
                //If the type is a concrete type we get here...
                service = _container.GetInstance(serviceType);
            }
            else
            {
                // Non concrete resolution which uses the base dependency resolver if needed.
                service = _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
            }
            return service;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem using a Ninject based resolver.  The solution in that case was to ensure that Ninject had a binding for IDependencyResolver, similar to this.

```cs
var resolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);
kernel.Bind<IDependencyResolver>().ToConstant(resolver);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

`AckSubscriber` has 2 constructors.

```cs
public AckSubscriber(IDependencyResolver resolver)
public AckSubscriber(IMessageBus messageBus, IAckHandler ackHandler)
```

It would appear that for some reason, rather than trying to create this class via a dependency resolver, it is trying to create this class via the underlying IOC container.  Because the bindings for all of this classes are in the `DefaultDependencyResolver`, the container has no idea what they are and so errors.  By specifying a binding for `IDependencyResolver` it is able to use the first constructor and work as intended.