# SignalR: resolving IMessageBus

Tags: asp.net, signalr, structuremap, signalr-hub

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790433/signalr-dependency-injection-questions) way for injecting dependencies into my Hub classes:

```
public class StructureMapDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
        private readonly IContainer _container;
        public StructureMapDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            _container = container;
        }
        public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return !serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface && serviceType.IsClass
                               ? _container.GetInstance(serviceType)
                               : (_container.TryGetInstance(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType));
        }
        public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType).Cast<object>().Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
        }
 }
```

And for use that, I have these lines of code in `Global.asax`:

```
SmObjectFactory.Container.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.For<IDependencyResolver>().Singleton().Add<StructureMapDependencyResolver>();
            });
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IDependencyResolver>();
```

It worked like a charm in SignalR version 2.1.2, But after upgrading to SignalR version 2.2.0 I get this error:

```
No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.IMessageBus'

There is no configuration specified for Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.IMessageBus

1.) new AckSubscriber(*Default of IMessageBus*, *Default of IAckHandler*)
2.) Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.AckSubscriber
3.) Instance of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.AckSubscriber
4.) Container.GetInstance(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.AckSubscriber)
```

It says that it can't resolve IMessageBus! I have tried this solution ([+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448652/structuremap-and-signalr-imessagebus-no-default-instance-defined)), But it didn't solve the problem.
Should I provide an implementation for that dependency? for example something like this:

```
x.For<IMessageBus>().Use<MessageBus>();
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/28242464/298573 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @VahidN, Actually I should have resolve from the base class first ([+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233885/signalr-structuremap-dependency-resolver-specified-for-microsoft-aspnet-signal/28242464#28242464)):

```
public override object GetService(Type serviceType) {
    if (serviceType == null) return null;

    var service = base.GetService(serviceType);
    if (service != null) return service;

    return (!serviceType.IsAbstract && !serviceType.IsInterface && serviceType.IsClass) ? _container.GetInstance(serviceType) : _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);
}
```